# Firefox shows apache 2 test page, while internet explorer works just fine

Tags: javascript, apache, firefox, testing

When I am trying to access Topspeed.com, my internet explorer shows the page just fine, but if I try firefox then I end up on the apache 2 test page... any idea why ?

Comment: How is this related to programing? Are you the creator of Topspeed.com? Are you wondering if there are ways to program that site in such as way as to fix this problem?

Comment: works for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Is Apache installed on your local machine?
E.g. if you open up a working browser (in your case, IE) and try to access http://127.0.0.1/, does this test page appear?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the subdomains are not set up correctly, IE:

http://www.topspeed.com will show ok but
http://topspeed.com will direct to another location

If you are concerned about this you can contact the website owner and have them update their domain settings.